# Error sending http post request with image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, http, post

I'm stucked in this problem since days and i really need your help.

I'm actually trying to upload a file from my iphone app to a webserver trough a php script.

this is my method in Xcode:

```
-(void)sendPost{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"myscriptishere.php";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\"myfile.png\"\r\n"] 
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

and my php code is:

```
<?php
    $domainpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $target = "./upload";
    $public = "/public/upload/";
    $target = $target.basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']) ;
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                           $domainpath. $public . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    echo "YES";

    else
    echo "NO";


    ?>
```

I always receive (after few seconds, so I guess I'm uploading something) the server reply "NO".

I already checked I have permission on the folder I'm going to write in.

Any ideas on where the problem could be hidin?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Maybe you messed up the $_FILES['userfile'] and $_FILES["file"] keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
NSString *urlString = @"myscriptishere.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

You are posting to a filename. Your `urlString` variable should hold full address including protocol and domain (like `@"http://localhost/myscriptishere.php"`).

Comment: obviously i meant @"h.t.t.p://www.mywebsite.com/myscript.php". My app connects succesfully to the website and to the script, but I receive a "NO" as response to my "POST"